# Is there anyone can interpret the results about basic regular expression using R?

Tags: r, regex

1.

```
test1
# [1] "abcd" "abc1" "ab2b" "a3cd" "4bcd"    
test1[grep('[^abc1-3]', test1)]
# [1] "abcd" "a3cd" "4bcd"
test1[grep('[^a-d1-3]', test1)]
# [1] "4bcd"
test1[grep('[^4]', test1)]
# [1] "abcd" "abc1" "ab2b" "a3cd" "4bcd"
```

2.

```
test5 <- c('lo', 'lol', 'lolo', 'olo', 'lool')
test5[grep('loll*', test5)]
# [1] "lol"  "lolo"
```

3.

```
test5
# [1] "lo"   "lol"  "lolo" "olo"  "lool"
test5[grep('lolo+', test5)]
# [1] "lolo"
test5[grep('lol+', test5)]
# [1] "lol"  "lolo"
```

I'm studying basic contents about regular expression using R.
But I can't understand why above three examples return those results.

For example, when using ^ in [], I learned that it returns the characters which don't involve the letters behind ^. But results don't seem like that.

I'm not good at English so I have difficulty in explaining all kinds of thing that I can't understand but I'll really appreciate if anyone can teach me why those results are returned by those R codes.

:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that `"[^abc1-3]"` will match any character that is not in {a, b, c, 1, 2, 3}.

`grep` will return TRUE if there is any match, and FALSE if there is no match.

```
test1
# [1] "abcd" "abc1" "ab2b" "a3cd" "4bcd"    
test1[grep('[^abc1-3]', test1)]
# [1] "abcd" "a3cd" "4bcd"
```

The three results have `d`, which is not in `{a, b, c, 1, 2, 3}`, so `d` is matched (the last one has `4`, which is also matched). The two test items that are not in the results, `"abc1"` and  `"ab2b"` only have characters in `{a, b, c, 1, 2, 3}`, so there is no match.

Regex101 is a good site for testing regular expressions and seeing how they work. Here is this example: https://regex101.com/r/CaxfCI/1

For your other examples,

- `*` means *0 or more*. So `'loll*'` matches `lol` followed by 0 or more `l`.
- `+` means *1 or more*. So  `'lol+'` matches `lo` followed by 1 or more `l`.

Note, for `grep`, there is not any point in `'loll*'`... the result will be the same as for `'lol'`. But in other regex operations, if you are *replacing* (substituting) or *extracting* the matches, the difference can matter.